# Combine arrays of identical length into array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 10 arrays of data that look like this:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
var arr2=['hello','hello1','hello2','hello3','hello4','hello5','hello6','hello7','hello8','hello9']
...8 More Arrays
```

Each array will have exactly the same number of elements every time. I wanted to know the best way to generate an array of objects that look like this that combines the various arrays:

```
overallarray = [{
arr1 = 1,
arr2 = 'hello'
...
},
{
arr1 = 2,
arr2 = 'hello1'
...
}]
```

I recognize that I can use a large number of for loops but am looking for a more optimized solution that someone might have.

Comment: Why is your data setup that way??

Comment: you only need one loop, you recycle the index to dupe each property needed from each array. one loop, many assignments to a blank object.

Comment: dandavis is right -- if you are assured that each array is the exact same length, then looping over any one of the arrays once, and simply reusing the current iterator value will do just what you need.

Comment: @DakotaBrown : I did miss it between the lines that `arr1` can't be desired property name, so I slightly improved my answer, you may consider using it, since it not just scales nicely, but may assign property names that can't be variable name and, which is important, works [significantly faster](https://jsbench.me/21k6o1yg4b/1), especially, for larger datasets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is where `Array.map()` will be your friend. You can iterate through any of the arrays (since they have the same number of elements) and then access each element by index to get the corresponding value for each array in your dataset, like so:

```js
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
var arr2=['hello','hello1','hello2','hello3','hello4','hello5','hello6','hello7','hello8','hello9'];
var arr3=['foo','foo1','foo2','foo3','foo4','foo5','foo6','foo7','foo8','foo9'];

let mapped = arr.map((elem, index) => {
  return {
    arr1: arr[index],
    arr2: arr2[index],
    arr3: arr3[index]
  }
});

console.log(mapped);
```

Edit: If you wanted to access them generically, you can add all of your arrays to one dictionary and iterate over the key/value pairs, like so:

```js
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
var arr2=['hello','hello1','hello2','hello3','hello4','hello5','hello6','hello7','hello8','hello9'];
var arr3=['foo','foo1','foo2','foo3','foo4','foo5','foo6','foo7','foo8','foo9'];
// combine all arrays into single dataset
let data = {arr, arr2, arr3};

let mapped = arr.map((elem, index) => {
  // iterate over the key/value pairs of the dataset, use the key to generate the 
  // result object key, use the value to grab the item at the current index of the 
  // corresponding array
  return Object.entries(data).reduce((res, [key, value]) => {
    res[key] = value[index];
    return res;
  }, {});
});

console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: small wrinkle, he has 10 arrays to do this with, which I think is sort of a lot to do in that return statement.

Comment: @Jhecht I mean how else would you combine those 10 arrays? They'd have to be combined manually in some way

Comment: @Jhecht Updated to include the case for handling the arrays generically inside the `.map()`

Comment: @NicholasSiegmundt actually it is possible to combine all the arrays if the names are progressive arr1, arr2, ..., arr10: `a = {}; a['arr' + 1] = eval('arr' + 1);` and so in a for loop you get the all the arrays without writing them manually one by one.

Comment: @lainatnavi Technically? Yes. Practically? Probably not. Should this be done? Definitely not.

Comment: @mhodges This is what I was looking for, to provide some clarification as to why my data is being moved around in such an odd way, I am integrating several SAAS platforms not originally designed to work together and each have their own set of data requirements both in format and function that I am having to work around.

Comment: Worth noting that the array names are not necessarily progressive.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `arr1`,`arr2` are not desired names of resulting object properties, if you need something

- that scales nicely for arbitrary number of data arrays
- assigns arbitrary key names (not necessarily corresponding to array variable names, or, worse, property name(s) that can't be valid variable name are needed)
- works [muuuch faster](https://jsbench.me/21k6o1yg4b/1) than accepted solution ;)

You may do the following:

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
      arr2=['hello','hello1','hello2','hello3','hello4','hello5','hello6','hello7','hello8','hello9'],
      
      keyNames = ['id', 'greeting'],
      
      group = (...arrays) => (keys) =>
        arrays.reduce((res, arr, idx) => 
          (arr.forEach((e,i) => res[i][keys[idx]] = e), res), 
          Array.from({length:arrays[0].length}, () => ({}))
        )
      
console.log(group(arr1,arr2)(keyNames))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate all arrays with 1 loop counter:

```
    var dataArrayOne = [1, 2, 3, 4 ];
    var dataArrayTwo = ["hello", "hello1", "hello2", "hello3" ];
...

    var resultArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        var combined = {
            arr1: dataArrayOne[I],
            arr2: dataArrayTwo[i]
...
        };

        resultArray.push(combined);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get from this:

```
[  [1, 2, 3]
,  [4, 5, 6]
,  [7, 8, 9]
]
```

to this:

```
[  [1, 4, 7]
,  [2, 5, 8]
,  [3, 6, 9]
]
```

with this function:

```
const combine =
  (...arrs) =>
    [ arrs.map(xs => xs[0])
    , ... (  arrs.every(xs => xs.length === 1)
              ? []
              : combine(...arrs.map(xs => xs.slice(1)))
          )
    ];


combine
  (  [1, 2, 3]
  ,  [4, 5, 6]
  ,  [7, 8, 9]
  );
```

Then from this:

```
[  [1, 4, 7]
,  [2, 5, 8]
,  [3, 6, 9]
]
```

to this:

```
[ {arr1: 1, arr2: 4, arr3: 7}
, {arr1: 2, arr2: 5, arr3: 8}
, {arr1: 3, arr2: 6, arr3: 9}
]
```

with this function:

```
const to_obj =
  (...arrs) =>
    arrs.map(arr =>
      Object.fromEntries(
        arr.map((x, i) => [`arr${i+1}`, x])));

to_obj
  ( [1, 4, 7]
  , [2, 5, 8]
  , [3, 6, 9]
  )
```

Hopefully connecting the two functions together is straightforward.

---

**A note about performance**

With exactly 10 arrays of 10 elements each, it is unlikely that you can tell whether a particular solution performs better than another. You should probably go for the solution that feels right in terms of readability or maintenance.

By these criteria you  should probably exclude mine; just wanted to share a different approach.