# How to change from array of values to array of objects?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I got data like this:

```
{"my_data":{"labels":[1,2,3,...], "idx":["idx1", "idx2", ...]}}
```

But I need it like this:

```
["my_data":{"labels":1, "idx": "idx1"},{"labels":2, "idx": "idx2"},... ]
```

I tried to loop like this to change the format:

```
var arr = [];
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(my_data)) {
    arr.push({[key]:value});
}
console.log(key, value);
```

But the result is a format I can not use with ag-grid

```
labels: [1,2,...]
idx: [idx1, idx2,...]
```

Comment: Do you mean you need it like this - `[{"labels":1, "idx": "idx1"},{"labels":2, "idx": "idx2"},... ]`?

Comment: yes........ @goto1

Comment: you might want to check out [one of my recent answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60233001/combine-arrays-of-identical-length-into-array-of-objects/60233331#60233331) which solves the similar problem

Comment: There is no JSON involved here. Please read the usage description of the `json` tag. It is not appropriate here.

Comment: `["my_data":{"labels":1, "idx": "idx1"},{"labels":2, "idx": "idx2"},... ]` is not valid a Javascript data structure. Javascript does not have associative arrays, only indexed arrays. Are you looking for a `map`?

Comment: @connexo need to change that structure yes , I will check now the solutions provided. thanks

Comment: Does that work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can approach this is by using the `map` method like in the following example:

```js
const temp = { my_data: { labels: [1, 2, 3], idx: ["idx1", "idx2", "idx3"] } };

const result = temp.my_data.labels.map((label, index) => {
  const idx = temp.my_data.idx[index];

  return {
    label,
    idx
  };
});

console.log(result)
```

This way, you're mapping through `labels` then extracting the value for `idx` based on the `index` of the `label`.

Comment: many thanks @goto1. question please I have a key like this `data two` how I can reference that space in code ?

Comment: @Wel can you give an example and the expected output?

Comment: look in your code I can reference in code labels like this `my_data.labels` but I have another field or key is two words with a space ! how I can reference this in code ?

Comment: on like you mean `const dataTwo = temp.my_data["data two"][index]`, like so?